# Unable to import Qt5Compat.QtGraphicalEffects in qt6 (qt for python)

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside6

Am aware that QtGraphicalEffects are now in commercial qt version.
But according to docs I can access some components like "ColorOverlay" through Qt5Compat. With c++ I added `QT += qt5compat`
In project.pro file and it worked.
How can I do the same in python. I want to use QtGraphicalEffects with qml and qt for python.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem, by using PySide2. I think it is not ported in more resent versions yet.